# Extracting the first paragraph of an article using PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I want to extract the first paragraph of an article using RegEx and PHP. I started to write a RegEx as below:

```
'/<p([^>]+)>(.*)<\/p>/i'
```

That's doing the job but the only little bug is that while markup is minified and in a one line as below:

```
<p>First Paragraph</p><p>SecondParagraph</p>
```

It simply matches all `<p>First Paragraph</p><p>SecondParagraph</p>`.
Also, I know that a paragraph could not be inside another one but I have no control on what user writes so he may do something like this and the RegEx would return unexpected result in this case as below:

```
<p>
    First Paragraph
    <p>SecondParagraph</p>
</p>
```

Now the RegEx matches `<p>First Paragraph<p>SecondParagraph</p>` but should extract `<p>First Paragraph<p>SecondParagraph</p></p>`.

Answer (score 0):

I reference the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/268074

And suggest you use Simple HTML DOM:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

```
str_get_html($string)->find('p')->plaintext;
```

Comment: This is still missing the final </p>.

Comment: @Petah Using a third-party is always horrible, I'm not sure that's really worthy to use it for just a simple and one-time-usage proccess.

Comment: @OmidAmraei I'm not sure you appreciate the detailed intricacies of HTML/XML. Simple HTML DOM is one of the more simple libraries to use for such a case. If not, then you could use [Query Path](http://querypath.org/), or [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). But regex is probably not the best solution.